# how to use Json() function in .net core web?

Tags: asp.net-core

I find that there is a function :`Json()` in the .net core webapi it is awesome but in the .net core web there is not here.

how can I use it in the .net core web?

like : `return Json(list)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return `JsonResult` , which is intended to return JSON-formatted data :

```
public JsonResult JsonActionResult()
{
    var data = new { Name = "Alex", LastName = "DeLarge" };

    return Json(data);
}
```

The `Json(object data)` function will create `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.JsonResult` that serializes the specified data to JSON format for the response.You can click [here](http://hamidmosalla.com/2017/03/29/asp-net-core-action-results-explained/) for more details about Asp.Net Core Action Results .

If you are using Razor pages , you can directly return `JsonResult`.

Comment: There is no Json in the .net core web.which says current context not exist Json

Comment: Did you use `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;`?

Comment: yes but not work @scharnyw says I should inherit from Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controller I will try it

Comment: @daotian , if you are using asp.net core razor pages , use `JsonResult` not `Json` . for example :`return new JsonResult(new Product { Id = stateid, Name = "Tom" });`